# Numpy C-API: PyArrayObject provides wrong dimensions

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm trying to get acess to the array dimensions of a numpy array within C.

**src.c**

```
static PyObject*
array_dims(PyObject *NPY_UNUSED(ignored), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyArrayObject *arg1=NULL;
    int i;

    // check for exactly one input argument and parse it to arg1
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyArray_Type, &arg1)) return NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < PyArray_NDIM(arg1); i++){
        printf("%d \n", PyArray_DIMS(arg1)[i]);
    }

    return(Py_None);
}
```

**run.py**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[7,8,9]])
src.dims(arr)
```

**console output**

```
3
0
```

The first one is correct, but for i=1 the shape should be 3 aswell. Further investigation showed that for i=2 (manually called) the output is "3" aswell, could be by chance, or maybe some systematic error.

I also tried arg1->dimensions or PyArray_SHAPE(arg1) but both showed the same result.

Comment: Wait, your `array_dims` function expects exactly one argument, but you're passing it two?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit for better reading, I corrected that mistake in the example.

Comment: Is `%d` actually the right format specifier? `npy_intp` isn't necessarily `int`.

Comment: I tryed also typecasting it to int, which didn't make a difference. I also compared the size of int and npy_intp which is both 4B.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was some kind of bug with the latest numpy version and Python 3.4. After switching to Python 3.5 the function provides the expected behaviour.